# White background with md-colors

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-material

Using [`md-colors`](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdColors) from angular material, is it possible to set the background to white **without** defining a custom white pallet?

I thought I could use the grey pallet because the [documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/Theming/03_configuring_a_theme) says:

> background - grey (note that white is in this palette)

So I tried doing

```
<div md-colors="{background: 'grey-50'}">
```

but `grey-50` is still only a light grey colour, not white.

I tried `<div layout-padding md-colors="{background: 'white'}">` but the white pallet doesn't seem to exist in angular material.
I get the error `angular.js:13711 mdColors: couldn't find 'white' in the palettes.`, because there is no white pallet.

Is there any way to access the white colour from the grey pallet? ( a hue, opacity etc.)

If not, is there any way to access a white colour from any other pallet using angular material?

If all else fails I could define an entire white pallet/theme and use that, but I would rather avoid doing that if there is a correct way.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can find all palettes and their colors in the source in [the theme file](https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/src/core/services/theming/theme.palette.js).

It should be `A100` but I have not tried it.

```
<div md-colors="{background: 'grey-A100'}">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try giving opacity at your `grey-50`. Somtehing like this:

```html
<div md-colors="{background: 'grey-50-0.1'}">
```

(where `0.1` is the opacity)

Full documentation:
https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.2/api/directive/mdColors

Answer (score 1):

You can also take a look of Sander Elias colors and hues using `md-colors` found in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SHkXcAQDNPHWloBnVxrw?p=preview). It demonstrate the result of the color class name both for the foreground and background. Hope it may help.